# .htaccess, Rewriting ALL PHP Vars to folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get, variables

I got this problem. I want to write ALL my php vars to folders. For example:

`www.mypage.com/en/shows/1/` to

`www.mypage.com/index.php?language=en&section=shows&item=1`

or

`www.mypage.com/en/home/` to

`www.mypage.com/index.php?language=en&section=home`

This is what I got:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?language=$1&section=$2
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?language=$1&section=$2&item=$3
```

It works perfectly with `www.mypage.com/en/home/` to

`www.mypage.com/index.php?language=en&section=home`

but when I try with `www.mypage.com/en/shows/1/` to

`www.mypage.com/index.php?language=en&section=shows&item=1`

the var laguage disapears. I read some of the answers already posted here and find a couple of tutorials but to be honest I don't understand too much.

Thanks for your patience, I am a complete newbie. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that your first RewriteRule will always match instead of your second one. Something that matches `(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$` will always match `(.*)/(.*)/$` also, because the latter doesn't care what comes before it.

Ideally, you would want to put a `^` at the beginning to stop this, but if you can't or it doesn't work, you could always try just reversing the rules so that the one with three areas gets a chance to match first. And although the rewrite should prevent the second rule from matching, it would be good practice to add `[L]` after them both, unless there's another reason you can't. `[L]` means that if it matches, it won't try matching any other rules.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Rick. I'll study the syntax and the different values. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(\w+)/$ index.php?language=$1&section=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(\w+)/(\d+)/$ index.php?language=$1&section=$2&item=$3 [L]
```

I am assuming a 2 character language code